Within the shadow root of a web component, is it possible to access an element in a way other than using the part property?
I know that it is possible to access the labels of a shadow-root through the part property. Here is an example:

fate-breadcrumb::part(text) {
  font-size: 12px !important;
}

With this CSS rule I can style the 2  tags with the property part="text"
What I'm trying to do without success so far is to access only the last <span part="text"> to apply the rule font-weight: 700 !important
Here my tries:
fate-breadcrumb::part(text):last-of-type {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}

fate-breadcrumb::part(text):nth-last-of-type(1) {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}

fate-breadcrumb::part(container) span::part(text):last-child {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}

fate-breadcrumb::part(container) > a > span::part(text):nth-last-of-type(1) {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}

fate-breadcrumb::part(text).breadcrumb__text {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
}


The best option is to contact the author of the Web Component, they should not call everything part="text". Would you buy a car where every button is labeled the same?

You are dealing with an open shadowRoot:

So [component].shadowRoot gives you access to everything inside that shadowRoot
Inject <style>
You could inject a <style> into every Web Component
  document.querySelectorAll("my-component").forEach((cmp) => {
    cmp.shadowRoot.append(
      createElement("style", {
        textContent: `[part="text"]:last-of-type { background:lightgreen }`,
      }),
    )
  })

But that is not flexible
adopt a constructed stylesheet
Every shadowRoot can adopt a (in-memory) Stylesheet (aka Constructed StyleSheet)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/CSSStyleSheet
  const stylesheet = new CSSStyleSheet(); // global in-memory stylesheet
  stylesheet.replace(`[part="text"]:last-of-type { color:red }`)

  document.querySelectorAll("my-component").forEach((cmp) => {
    cmp.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [stylesheet]
  })

That way you can update the styles in all components with one call
  stylesheet.setColor = 
     (color) => stylesheet.replace(`[part="text"]:last-of-type { color:${color} }`)

full code:
A bit contrived, really want to show your required [part="text"]:last-of-type


<my-component>Cool</my-component>
<my-component>Great</my-component>
<my-component>Awesome</my-component>

<button onclick="stylesheet.setColor(this.textContent)">red</button>
<button onclick="stylesheet.setColor(this.textContent)">yellow</button>
<button onclick="stylesheet.setColor(this.textContent)">blue</button>

<script>
  const createElement = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props)
  customElements.define( "my-component", class extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {
        super().attachShadow({ mode: "open" }).append(
            createElement("style", {
                textContent: `:host{display:block;font:31px arial}` +
                             `[part="text"]:last-of-type { border:1px solid blue }`
            }),
            createElement("span", { textContent: "Hello ", part: "text" }),
            createElement("slot", { }),
            createElement("span", { textContent: " Web Component ", part: "text" }),
          )
      }})
  const stylesheet = new CSSStyleSheet(); // global in-memory stylesheet
  stylesheet.setColor = (color) => stylesheet.replace(`[part="text"]:last-of-type { color:${color} }`)
  document.querySelectorAll("my-component").forEach((cmp) => {
    cmp.shadowRoot.append(
      createElement("style", {
        textContent: `[part="text"]:last-of-type { background:lightgreen }`,
      }),
    )
    cmp.shadowRoot.adoptedStyleSheets = [stylesheet]
  })
</script>



